# Managing cordova plugin versions

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a cordova 7.1.0 app, which I'm developing on macOS 10.13.4 (High Sierra) and I'm having a tough time managing plugin versions, though it seems like it should be pretty straight forward.

I want to keep the `platforms` and `plugins` directories out of source control. I want to regenerate them every time clone the repo.

I also want to add plugins to my library at specific versions. I do not want it to download any bug fixes or minor releases (i.e. I want exactly version `1.2.3` not `^1.2.3` or `~1.2.3`).

So I tried to install a plugin like this:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mixpanel@4.2.0
```

It adds it fine but when I look inside `config.xml` I see

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-mixpanel" spec="^4.2.0" />
```

Not what I want. That means if version 4.3.0 comes out, the next time the plugins are downloaded, it will grab 4.3.0. I want to see this:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-mixpanel" spec="4.2.0" />
```

meaning that no matter when the plugin is downloaded, it will always grab version 4.2.0.

Similarly, package.json looks like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "cordova-plugin-mixpanel": "^4.2.0"
}
```

and it should look like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "cordova-plugin-mixpanel": "4.2.0"
}
```

How do I make this happen?

Comment: After adding a plugin, just edit the `package.json` and `config.xml` and remove the `^` as you have already shown.

Comment: @DaveAlden unfortunately, I tried that and it doesn't work. If you edit the files then delete the `plugins` directory, the next time you run `cordova platform add` and `cordova prepare` it will actually add the `^` back into `package.json` and `config.xml`. It's bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can achieve this through an npm setting. If you do

```
npm config set save-prefix=""
```

it will no longer add `^` or `~` to your package version numbers.

You can read more about the `save-prefix` setting [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#save-prefix). I ended up adding a `.npmrc` file with that setting inside of it to my cordova app directory so it will have that affect for everyone who runs cordova from that directory.